# Managing a big WinForm code

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010

I want to ask pro developers out there that how they manage a big windows form class. Is it a good idea to split it with `partial` keyword across different files? That's the thing that I was doing so far, but it creats unnecessry designer files that when you double click on them in VS, a blank winform will pop up:

[image]

So what I do, basically is group events and code logic for each related group of controls in one file.

Comment: @Bryan A windows form that exeecds 10000 lines of code...I think it's big!

Comment: I agree that is big.  See ivowiblo's answer below... time to refactor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My answer is "I don't". If you need a lot of code in one single class (in this case a form) it usually means your class is doing a lot of stuff and you need to make it less coupled. A good way to achieve this is to use a sort of MVC or MVP pattern form putting the logic in another place, and to use UserControls so you could have the different functionalities in different controls (with their controller or presenter, depending if you implement MVC or MVP). Divide and conquer.

Comment: I think that applying just MVP is not a completed answer, we can apply bad this concept and get 3 files, one for view (**sample.designer** file) another for the control (**sample.cs** file) and the last one for the model (**model.cs**). This pattern and others have to be accompanied with a good class/component design.

Comment: Yes, that's why I also suggested to make a cohesive model for the forms and controls. Anyway, you can always apply a concept badly.

Answer (score 0):

I not consider me an expert, but once we had a similar problem with a main form that did not stop growing up.

The solution was just OOP, make unattached and reusable classes, those can be in the same namespace with internal visibility.

For Example there you have a **ComparisionForm.Menu** that looks that can be unattached from your main code in **ComparisionForm**.

From another point of view **'Readability'**.- Partial classes are useful but take into account that even with that division of code in different files, the logic is not always divided, that makes the code hard to read, understand and finally hard to maintain.

Divide logically my classes for my was the solution. You know what say they "Divide and Conquer"

Comment: It seems "divide and conquer" is the slogan here :P

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to separate the code of a form, it's to use UserControl.

And in my case, when I have a big class, I use region instead of partial class.

Comment: Regions are the root of all evil

Comment: Big class is the root of all evil :)

Comment: Yep. But it'l like having a dirty room and instead of cleaning it, you hid it below the carpet.

Answer (score 0):

Not a pro, but my two cents are: *Don't* have a large class. Extract most of the code to other classes.

You'll gain, also, that you'll be able to make most of the methods `private`, thus reducing Intellisense "noise".